# Unable to install python-levenshtein package on Mac using Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was trying to install the `python-levenshtein` library using terminal. However, I kept encountering errors. The Python version that I am using is Python 3.6 and the command I had been using to install the package is `pip install python-levenshtein`.

Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thank you.

[image: Terminal Error]

Comment: Do you have a C compiler installed?

Comment: Perhaps show us more info?

Answer (score 3):

For Anaconda users, it is better use the following command as it helped in my case:

```
conda install -c conda-forge python-levenshtein
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your computer have both python2 and python3 installed, if that is the case, you should use pip3 install python-levenshtein.

Comment: I did try that, I still ended up with the same error.

Comment: If you error message is about the failed building wheel, then i think you also have to install wheel before you install your package.

Comment: It worked, for some reason you need to have Xcode installed on your Mac for it to work.