# python-Levenshtein library install error on MacOS

Tags: python, macos, pip, pycharm, anaconda

I am trying to install a package on a python project but having some issues with python-Levenshtein library. I'm using a virtual environment on PyCharm which is running with Python3.8 and installed all libraries in requirements.txt with pip. However I am not able to install this library.

What I've tried so far:

1. try to install with pip and pip3
2. try to install with anaconda
3. try to install with brew (to make sure it's not like matplotlib [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25701133/how-to-tell-homebrew-to-install-inside-virtualenv))

I share the error message below. Could you help me to solve this problem

```
Collecting python-Levenshtein==0.12.0
  Using cached python-Levenshtein-0.12.0.tar.gz (48 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /Users/suleyman/Projects/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from python-Levenshtein==0.12.0) (51.1.1)
Building wheels for collected packages: python-Levenshtein
  Building wheel for python-Levenshtein (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for python-Levenshtein (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
  Running setup.py clean for python-Levenshtein
Failed to build python-Levenshtein
Installing collected packages: python-Levenshtein
    Running setup.py install for python-Levenshtein: started
    Running setup.py install for python-Levenshtein: finished with status 'error'

  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
```

Comment: Did [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43312282/unable-to-install-python-levenshtein-package-on-mac-using-python-3-6) answer your question ?

Comment: I've tried that. Unfortunately doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution and explain it for those who suffers from the same thing. Macbook comes with its own python in `usr/bin/python` and `user/bin/python3` and first I used them as base interpreter however I faced that issue. I think default pythons don't include some essentials.

The solution is installing your [python](https://www.python.org/downloads/mac-osx/) and giving its path as the base interpreter. After that `pip` is able to install the library.

[image]

That solved my issue and I am able to install my libraries.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do `python3 -m pip install python-levenshtein` or if you want to install system-wide just do the `sudo -H python3 -m pip install python-levenshtein`.

P.S. It works for me.
[image]

Comment: Unfortunately no chance but I've found the solution. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

Try installing `libpython3.8-dev` (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32595050/sudo-pip-install-python-levenshtein-failed-with-error-code-1))

I was running into the same build error on Ubuntu 18.04 until I ran

```sh
sudo apt install libpython3.8-dev
```

Then, inside my python virtual environment, I ran

```
python3 -m pip install python-Levenshtein
```

If that doesn't work, check that you have `build-essential` installed. If not, then try:

```
sudo apt install build-essential
```